# Firefox/jQuery is not reading any attribute for an img element

Tags: jquery, firefox, attributes

So I am attempting to combine two image galleries, [Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) and [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).  The way it is supposed to work is that Lightbox will read the *href* from the anchor tag and Galleria will read the *src* from the image tag in the following code:

```
<a href="./public/images/gallery/2.JPG">
<img class="replaced" src="./public/images/gallery/2.JPG"/>
</a>
```

I am attempting to pull the attribute value of the src out and use it as the value of the href.  Just for now, once I get this bit working I have to re-work the code.

This is how I am pulling the attribute value out

```
var imageSrc = image.attr('src');
```

Right now I have tested it in FF2,FF3 and neither of them are reading the value.  In Chrome and IE it reads the value.  What I was thinking is that the image is created in jQuery so perhaps Firefox is moving too quickly reading through and the jQuery hasn't had time to create the image yet?

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Levi

Comment: how are you selecting the 'image' ?

Comment: What does the variable "image" contain? What happens if you write "var imageSrc = $('img.replaced').attr('src');" instead?

Comment: image is part of a function which refers to this line
var _img   = $(new Image()).attr('src',_src).addClass('replaced');

Answer (score 0):

Well how are you selecting image?

Try:

```
$('.replaced').each(function(){
   var imageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
   //alert(imageSrc) /*  for IE  */
   console.log(imageSrc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Did you define `image` correctly? How are you assigning a value to this?
- Did you ask for the value of `image` after the position of the DOM element representing that image?
- Did you make sure to put your scripts at the end of your body, just before the closing `</body>` tag? (If you don't, it's possible you'll wind up with a null reference and any Javascript execution will terminate.)

Chances are good that it's related to one of these three issues.

Comment: Why would he need to put his script at the end of the body?! That's what the ready event is for

Comment: image is a parameter of a function, it refers to this line where it is set:
var _img = $(new Image()).attr('src',_src).addClass('replaced');

I am creating the image in one JS file and then in the JS file following it I assign create and assign the value of the anchor tag.  It seems to be in the correct order, I mean it does work in IE and Chrome, does FF have a different order for doing things?

Comment: This is the url of what I am working on, I have firebug open but I am new to it and don't know how to use it fully.  http://www.lewiscreekbuilders.com/test/?gallery-with-testimonials/gallery/?galId=62#./public/images/gallery/2.JPG

Comment: @Nadia: I don't know if he using the ready event or not. But doing so removes a possible source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping your call in a ready event?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imageSrc = $('img.replaced').attr('src');
});
```

Please note that if you have multiple images that share the class 'replaced' you need to read the src from each one of them. The above method will only work on a single image, if you want to read the attribute for multiple images use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imageSrc = $('img.replaced').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is wrapped, and there is only one instance of an image with a class of 'replaced'.  You can see what I am working on at this url http://www.lewiscreekbuilders.com/test/?gallery-with-testimonials/gallery/?galId=62#./public/images/gallery/2.JPG